# Who are all of the companions and how do I get them?

Tags: fallout-4

I have quite the number of companions and I've just scratched the surface of Boston. I'm wondering if there is a definitive list of companions and information on how to get them all to join me on my crusade!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a [pretty handy guide for all of the 13 companions you can receive](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/fallout-4-companion-guide-locations-and-perks-all-13-companions-489421).

You can "recruit":

- **Codsworth** (Robot)

  - Location: Sanctuary
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: Robot Sympathy
- **Dogmeat** (Doge)

  - Location: Red Rocket Truck Stop
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: None
- **Paladin Danse** (Human)

  - Location: Cambridge Police Station
  - Associated Quest: Call to Arms
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Know Your Enemy
- **Piper** (Human)

  - Location: Diamond City
  - Associated Quest: Location Quest: Story of the Century
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Gift of Gab
- **Preston Garvey** (Human)

  - Location: Museum of Freedom
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: United We Stand
- **Nick Valentine** (Synth)

  - Location: Vault 114 (Park Street Station)
  - Associated Quest: Side Quest: Long Time Coming
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: Close to Metal
- **Cait** (Human)

  - Location: Combat Zone
  - Associated Quest: Side Quest (Companion): Benign Intervention
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Trigger Rush
- **Curie** (Robot)

  - Location: Vault 81
  - Associated Quest: Side Quest (Companion): Emergent Behavior
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Combat Medic
- **X6-88** (Synth)

  - Location: The Institute
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: Shield Harmonics
- **Strong** (Mutant)

  - Location: Trinity Tower
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: Berserk
- **Deacon** (Human)

  - Location: Old North Church
  - Associated Quest: None
  - Romance: No
  - Perk: Cloak & Dagger
- **John Hancock** (Ghoul)

  - Location: Goodneighbor
  - Associated Quest: Miscellaneous: Recruiting Hancock
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Isodoped
- **MacCready** (Human)

  - Location: The Third Rail (Goodneighbor)
  - Associated Quest: Side Quest (Companion): Long Road Ahead
  - Romance: Yes
  - Perk: Killshot

Comment: Dogmeat's an Italian cheif of state?

Comment: One of those "humans" is not. Might add the actual race in a spoiler tag.

Answer (score -3):

I think the best companion in the game is the Romance Paladin Danse. He is the strongest companion in Fallout 4.

**General Profile**

**Gender**: Male

**Race**: Human/Synth

**Faction**: The Brotherhood of Steel     |     Rank: Paladin

**Main Personality Traits**: Devoted, Loyal, Aggressive, Righteous, Fearless

**Hair Color**: Black     |     Eye Color: Light Brown

**Companion Perk**: Know Your Enemy (20% more damage against irradiated ghouls, mutated humanoids and androids)

Here is the complete guide to getting this companion. http://www.reviewpost.net/?p=490

Comment: What about the rest of the companions?  This is only one of many.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your answer. 1. It is opinionated and only mentions a single companion. No one asked for a recommendation on who was the best companion. 2. It doesn't say how to get Paladin Danse in the answer, it provides a link to an external site that tells how to get him.