# Is there anything we can do to locate companions in the world easier?

Tags: fallout-4

Keeping track of where everyone is is *hard*.

I could be out in the wasteland while Dogmeat will let me know he found something. That's great, but then it's a chore trying to find him a lot of times. Sometimes, he'll even run ahead and attack enemies and I'll lose sight of him. Only if I leave an area sufficiently far enough, he'll come back and meet with me which isn't always possible. I know I can listen out for him but visual indicators would be better. But none of this works if I sent him to a settlement but needed to find him and he hasn't returned yet.

**Is there anything we can do to make locating companions in the world easier?**

Comment: That answers the settler part, but I am more interested on the companion.  It might be that there is nothing we can do at the moment, but I wouldn't say it's the same.

Comment: It's not a duplicate at all. Companions =/= Settlers.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know how one could get the idea that they are the same question. I asked the other question (about settlers) and I was talking about a menu with a list of all the people at a camp and what they are doing. Which is a totally different thing from locating a *companion's* physical place in the game world.

Comment: This issue is compounded by companions disappearing. I sent Codsworth back to Sanctuary when Preston accompanied me and I've not seen Codsworth since!

Comment: @DavidYell Locating where dismissed companions are is another issue. I think the asker wants to know where their active companion has run off to. I would also like to know this.

Comment: +1 here. Especially would like to know for those times when I tell Dogmeat to "stay" out of my way for awhile, and then forget where I left him.

Comment: @DavidYell Did you ever find Codsworth? I can't think of a reason why he shouldn't be in Sanctuary, but I haven't finished the game yet either.

Comment: @Iszi No, I've stopped looking after a few full sweeps of Sanctuary, and accepted that he's vanished.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a few different situations where one might lose track of a companion. Most of these can be worked around with relative ease, but others practically beg for console assistance.

- While They Are Following You

  - Companion gets distracted by "shiny thing" (runs off to fight enemy or pick up an item).
  - Companion falls in combat.
  - Companion is told to wait, and you forget where.

Without the console, these pretty much require one of three fixes:

1. Brute-force search of the area.
2. Run away and wait for them to catch up.
3. Fast-travel.

The first solution will, of course, always work. Eventually. As long as you're thorough and patient.

Running away or fast-traveling will certainly work for distracted or fallen companions, but I haven't tested it for companions who have been ordered to stay in a certain location. I expect that, in those cases, running away definitely won't work. Until I get a chance to test, I'd guess fast-traveling would probably work but won't guarantee it.

Also be aware that, for fallen companions, there is one more fix: Clear out the enemies in your immediate area, and wait for the companion to arise and return to you.

- While They Are Not Following You

  - You dismiss a companion and subsequently cannot find them at the location you sent them to.
  - You never actually pick up the companion after they've asked (or been asked) to join you for the first time.
  - Random disappearances of idle companions.

These can really stretch your patience if you don't have the console because, well, you're playing on a console. (I play on Xbox One. So, if you want a PC console fix, you'll have to check @kalina's answer.) But they can generally be worked around. The first case is one that sent me Googling for an answer, and even then I didn't find the right answer for my situation (included as the last fix below). The latter is something I haven't personally encountered yet but, given the experience I had with solving the former, it seems very possible that it might happen.

Some solutions for this group are:

1. Search the settlement you sent them to.

   - For most cases, just running about and checking the common areas of the settlement will turn up your missing companion.
   - For Dogmeat specifically, check inside or near any doghouses in the settlement. It's best if you just build one for him in a place that you'll remember.
   - To help consolidate settlers and companions into one place, you could try using a bell. You may want to try moving the bell and re-trying it in multiple locations in the settlement - depending on how your settlement's structures are arranged, and where the resident NPCs are when you ring it, it's very possible that not everyone will find their way to the bell in every location.
   - You could also try waiting until night time and doing a bed search. Not everyone will necessarily be in bed, but this still helps increase the probability that you'll be looking somewhere your companion actually is.
   - In case you're mis-remembering a companion's assigned settlement, you might want to check your settlements' population counts in the Pip-Boy and go search all inhabited settlements.
   - In case they might be "right in front of you, where you can't see them" try using VATS to highlight targets in the area.  Keep in mind that "targets" refers to any NPC or creature, regardless of whether they're friendly or hostile, and any turrets. So this could get a bit noisy in highly-populated or well-defended settlements. Also, this won't work if the companion is actually following you at the time (hence why this isn't in the earlier section).
2. Check their original residence.

   - [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242796/who-are-all-of-the-companions-and-how-do-i-get-them) has a list of their locations, and a link to another guide.
   - Companions will generally wait at their original residence if you don't choose to have them follow you immediately after gaining their companionship.
   - There's also been some claims that a bug sometimes causes dismissed companions to go to their original residence instead of their assigned settlement.
3. 1 and/or 2, plus waiting.

   - Companions don't just instantly teleport anywhere under normal circumstances. (For a probable exception, see the next solution.) You might actually have to burn off some in-game time (wait/sleep) for them to get to wherever they're going before you'll be able to find them there.
4. Go about your business.

   - If a companion is supposed to be involved in the next step of a quest, and they're not actively following you, they may be found at the location of that next step. I had this happen with Piper recently. I dismissed her while I was in Sanctuary, and told her to stay in Sanctuary, and subsequently couldn't find her anywhere in a settlement or the Publick Occurences office. It wasn't until I picked up the main quest line again that I stumbled across her at the location of the next step.

Comment: Thanks, this is more in the spirit of what I'm asking. Short answer to companions traveling with you, there's no way to find out where they are around you except visually seeing them, no indicators, no "look at companion" button, nothing.

Comment: If you tell a companion to "Stay" somewhere, they will stay there even if you fast travel away. This has been the case in every Elder Scrolls and Bethesda Fallout game I've played, and it seems to be the case here as well.

Comment: @DCShannon Thanks for the feedback. I'll sanity-check and edit it in later.

Comment: @DCShannon Good point. I use the same trick all the time to spot enemies I haven't visually noticed. I'll add that in later too.

Comment: One thing that I have found useful in locating a companion that is truly lost is to load a "save" before the loss. It may require you to replay some parts but it does resolve the issue of not having your companion.

Comment: I've determined that I was wrong earlier when I said VATS targets companions. It will target temporary followers like Danse at Arcjet or Dogmeat on the way to the fort, or companions in town, but not your current, actual companion.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah, I thought that was the situation. Still useful for the second part of my answer, where you've lost a dismissed companion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

Not that I've found. They don't appear on any of the maps and although they will increment a settler count at settlements that also doesn't necessarily mean they're at that settlement (they could be travelling to it).

The only sure-fire method of finding a companion so far is to utilize the console in the PC version of the game. Using the console (by pressing ' or ~ depending on the keyboard layout in use) you can type the following:

```
prid 001d162
moveto player
```

This would move Dogmeat to your current location upon closing the console. The IDs for the other companions are as follows:

- Cait: 00079305
- Codsworth: 0001ca7d
- Curie: 00102249
- Paladin Danse: 0005de4d
- Deacon: 00045ac9
- Dogmeat: 0001d162
- John Hancock: 00022615
- Robert MacCready: 0002a8a7
- Nick Valentine: 00002f25
- Piper: 0002f1f
- Preston Garvey: 0001a4d7
- Strong: 0003f2bb
- X6-88: 0002e210a

Comment: Or you could set up a settlement made up entirely of companions. That would at least break down the places one would have to look for them. The smaller, the better.

Comment: I like Ben's idea, and that is what I did. But Dogmeat can go missing. Just build him a Dog house, and he is sure to be there.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, if you have access to the Vault-Tec Workshop DLC, you can craft a [Vault-Tec Population Management System Terminal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_Population_Management_System) to locate your companions.

According to [IGN's page](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-4/How_to_Locate_Your_Companions) for this device, you can use the terminal to place a tracker on your companions.

> However, one the best features of this cool little machine is the Access VIP tracker. Going into this menu option will allow you to select any of your currently recruited companions and place a marker at their location.
>
> Take a look at your map to see exactly where your companion has been hiding this entire time. You can even select the option to put a tracker on all of your companions. You can always switch the trackers off by removing them through the terminal, or deselecting the quest that begins the first time you place a tracker on a companion.

By using this terminal, it puts a marker on your map designating where that companion is located.  It should be matter of just making your way to them at this point.

Comment: Darn it, I *just* discovered this last night and was about to write an answer on it! :)

Comment: @Robotnik yoinked!

Answer (score 0):

On top of the standard approaches, there's also a mod that you can use now and works very well: http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/7903/?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the answer the OP was looking for, but for companions you can't find because you told them to stay somewhere and you forgot where there is an easy fix for non PC players. That is provided you have another companion hanging out somewhere.

Just go to a new companion and ask him to follow you.  The game will then ask where to send your current companion. Send him to the area of your choosing. Then go sleep for 10 hours or so and your lost companion should be where you sent him when you wake up.

As for locating dogmeat when he's found something the only way I've remedied this is by using headphones.

And just an extra tip. To make finding Dog a little easier at your settlement go around and scrap all the doghouse except one. Dog will usually be near the only doghouse in the settlement.

Comment: If you know that the answer you're giving is not what is being sought after, then you should leave a comment instead of answering.

Comment: Well it was kind of an answer to the question. But I see what you're saying. New to the site and green to the format

Comment: I don't mean to scare you away, but the questions and answers are meant to be formatted so that future users can easily read them.