# Nick Valentine disappeared... what to do?

Tags: fallout-4

Just before taking out the courser, when I was resupplying at the Castle, Nick disappeared. He was an active companion, and was with me at the Castle, but I could not find him by the time I left.

Fast traveling to another location did not help. I exchanged him for Cait, and sent Nick to Red Rocket. Looking on the map, Red Rocket had 1 settler (previously 0) so I killed the courser and headed to Red Rocket.

When I got there, Nick was not around and the settlers count was again 0.

I tried console commands, they do not work. Nick was not teleported to my location, or was invisible and silent. He is also not within Goodneighbor, any settlement, nor Diamond City.

I have no idea what to do next to get him back.

Comment: Was Nick with you at the Castle? When did he disappear? When you arrived, when you were there, or when you left?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, although it sounds like these solutions have been tried: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243316/is-there-anything-we-can-do-to-locate-companions-in-the-world-easier?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I'm using cranky phone (damn auto "correct"...). Yes it was Cait, yes I've meant "got". And Nick disappeared while I was at the Castle. I had him nearby and when I wanted to exchange some gear with him... he was gone.

Comment: That's really odd he would just wander off like that. Do you recall giving him any commands at the Castle? Maybe trading with him? It's possible you told him to wait, but then you would have probably found him when searching the Castle. How long has it been since you assigned him to Red Rocket? Maybe you need to give him some time to make the walk.

Comment: I gave him no command, herd nothing from him like during quest (while we had to go to Goodneighbor). It's now more than 48 in game hours. "Funny" thing that console command doesn't work... it should right?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely odd. I'm not sure what could cause the console to fail to move him. Only suggestions I have left are to wait a few more days, and try ringing a bell and doing a bed check at Red Rocket.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3sgkc5/lost_companions_in_fallout_4/) with a list of solutions you can try :

> - Make sure to look where you originally found the companion.
> - Search around the area you last left the companion. They tend to
>     wander around, maybe it just takes some looking.
> - Make sure to triple check around the area you sent them, it could be
>     you are overlooking their area.
> - PC users can use a specific code to teleport to them. Try
>     player.moveto (NPC ID) remove the parenthesis.
> - If you have most dog meat make sure you check your doghouses, he
>     usually hang around the ones that are a bit distance from the center
>     of the sanctuary.
> - Generally if you realized you lost a companion, try to retrace your
>     steps, and go back to the last quest, or area you were at. They could
>     be just standing there like bums.

Othersise, you can build a bell and try this :

> [...] If you go into the workshop menu when you’re at a settlement, head over to Resources> Miscellaneous, go two across, and you’ll come across the bell. Build one of these on your settlements and it will gather all of your nearby settlers when rung. Make sure it’s built in a central area where people can gather around it. This is the best way to try and get back any of your settlers who have gone missing, or just as a means of organizing your workforce for the settlement chores, as everyone eventually (although slowly) makes their way towards it. [(source)](http://twinfinite.net/2015/11/fallout-4-how-to-find-lost-settlers-and-companions/2/)

And finally, you can [read this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3sdoe8/nick_valentine_missing/), but be aware that you may be spoiled :

> "I have the same problem. I sent him back to his office but he isn't here now even after waiting over 24 hours. Edit: I figured out where he was! I dunno if you're at the same part of the quest as me, but on Reunions where you have to tell Piper about your findings, when I showed up in her office he was there too."

Comment: I've seen / tried all of it and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you finally find the solution, tell us what you've done ! I wish you the best luck...