# I somehow scrapped Nick Valentine, is my game broken?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

So I was scrapping some junk, and Nick Valentine walked by in front of me. I didn't pay attention to him and continued scrapping. I scrapped a pile, then turned to another. I was trying to scrap all the junk ASAP because I wanted to go back to looting the wilderness. Nick was standing in front of the pile, and before I realized he was there, I turned, pressed Square to scrap, and pressed X to confirm. Nick was gone. I had quickly looked at what materials I would get for scrapping what I thought was something in the pile, and it said '5 circuitry, 10 cloth, 15 steel' (Nick's 'materials'?) I reverted to an older save and he was there.

So scrapping companions is somehow possible? I would have never thought this was real. I even tried doing it a few more times, but no success. Is this a bug or some sort of hidden feature? I'm weirded out by this. I'm on the PS4, too, so no mods were on.

Comment: That's nuts, I've never heard of that before, that's hilarious.

Comment: I thought that maybe if you got your companions disliked you enough you could scrap, like another alternative instead of fighting them, but Nick loved me (I was about to do his personal mission, actually).

Comment: See that's a great theory... companion doesn't like you? Don't bother being nice to people in their company, just scrap them!

Comment: I suggest you try all the things in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/261333/163757) and if nothing works maybe try selecting another companion to follow you. I'm hoping that after trying that, the dialogue to send Nick to a settlement will appear. Send him somewhere, then check that location to see if he's there (I would chose a location that's a fair distance away).

Comment: You're playing a Creation engine game on a console, it was never *not* broken. (please add the PS4 tag ;)

Comment: I don't think that is supposed to happen but hey, if he ever annoys you just say "Nick, I will turn you into a bed so zip it"

Comment: Where is Fus Ro Da, when you need it.

Answer (score 5):

Although normally this isn't possible, Fallout 4 is not without its bugs.

There is [a way to force mods onto things they are not intended for](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/4u81su/forced_mod_attach_glitch_guide/).

You most likely was scrapping so fast that you somehow was able to target Nick with the scrap dialog, and end up actually scrapping him.

Comment: The fact that I received multiple items and not just '1 steel' makes me think that the developers actually thought about it.

Comment: Or it may have been the scrap for the items he way carrying, generally if you scrap a container you also scrap the contents...

Comment: @aslum that's not my experience.  If I scrap a container, the contents go to my stash.  A message pops up that tells me this happened.